# count the active classes on both choices

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on 2 selections, that adds active class on click and add disabled class on the opposite selection. My problem is how get the count of classes exist on both selection ex. selection1 = 1 and selection2 = 5. Also my counting and display of result is off.

Hope you help me thanks.

```js
$('.numChoice > .col-md-5ths > .num').on("click", function() {
    var idx = $(this).parent().index();
    var act = $(this).is(".active");
    var $otherSide = $(this).closest(".numChoice").siblings(); // plural but only one
    var $otherElement = $otherSide.find(".col-md-5ths").eq(idx).children(":first");
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $otherElement.toggleClass('disabled', !act);

    var len1 = $otherSide.find('.active').length;
    var len2 = $(this).closest('.numChoice').find('.active').length;
    console.log('selection1: ' + len1, 'selection2: ' + len2);

});
```

```css
.numChoice {
  display: block;
}

.num {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.num.active {
  color: green;
}

.num.disabled {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="numChoice first-row">
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="numChoice second-row">
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you want to count the active classes for the first row against the second row:

```
const firstRowActiveLabels = $('.numChoice.first-row .active').length;
const secondRowActiveLabels = $('.numChoice.second-row .active').length;
```

`.numChoice.first-row` means: get the class that has numChoice and has first-row classes.
`.active` means: and get the inner elements that has active class.

```js
$('.numChoice > .col-md-5ths > .num').on("click", function() {
    var idx = $(this).parent().index();
    var act = $(this).is(".active");
    var $otherSide = $(this).closest(".numChoice").siblings(); // plural but only one
    var $otherElement = $otherSide.find(".col-md-5ths").eq(idx).children(":first");
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $otherElement.toggleClass('disabled', !act);

    var len1 = $('.numChoice.first-row .active').length;
    var len2 = $('.numChoice.second-row .active').length;
    console.log('selection1: ' + len1, 'selection2: ' + len2);

});
```

```css
.numChoice {
  display: block;
}

.num {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.num.active {
  color: green;
}

.num.disabled {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="numChoice first-row">
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="numChoice second-row">
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've rewritten your JS part a bit. Please check if it's what you're looking for.

```js
$('.numChoice .num').on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')){
      return false; // let's skip disabled items?
    }
    var idx = $(this).parent().index();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    var act = $(this).is(".active");
    const $others = $(this).closest(".numChoice").siblings();
    $others.each(function(){
      const $opposite = $(this).find('.num').eq(idx);
      $opposite.removeClass('active').toggleClass('disabled', act);
    });
    updateCounts();

});

function updateCounts(){
  const len1 = $('.first-row .active').length;
  const len2 = $('.second-row .active').length;
  console.clear();
  console.log('selection1: ' + len1, 'selection2: ' + len2);
}
```

```css
.numChoice {
  display: block;
}

.num {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.num.active {
  color: green;
}

.num.disabled {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="numChoice first-row">
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="numChoice second-row">
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you're answer is correct, I can't two accept two answers